# La sesión se cierra antes del tiempo definido de expiración. PHP(session_start)

Tags: php, session

Estoy definiendo para que la sesión dure 12 horas activa y si existe alguna inactividad prolongada de 1 hora que se cierre la sesión.

No sé en que estoy fallando, pero la sesión se cierra aún si hay inactividad o no. Me explico, Aún manejando el sistema después de cierto tiempo la sesión se cierra y por inactividad también cierra la sesión con tiempo inferior al definido que es 1 hora.

Esta es la clase conexión, cada vista accede a la clase para traerse los datos de la DB, entonces aquí defino el `session_start`.

```
session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 43200,]); //Tiempo de 12 horas en segundos
        session_set_cookie_params(43200); 
        ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 43200);
        session_cache_expire(720);  //Tiempo de 12 horas en minutos

       //Este código es para verificar la inactividad y está en la misma clase
       if(isset($_SESSION['tiempo']) ) { //Aquí verifico si el tiempo actual está definido
           $vida_session = time() - $_SESSION['tiempo'];
           $inactivo = 3600; //Una hora en segundos
             if($vida_session >= $inactivo)
                {
                //Removemos sesión.
                session_unset();
                //Destruimos sesión.
                session_destroy();          
                //Redirigimos pagina.
                echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'>
                      alert('Su sesion ha caducado'); 
                      window.top.location='/assets/login'; 
                      </script>";
                exit();
                                }
                            }
        //Con esta línea defino el tiempo actual.
        $_SESSION['tiempo'] = time();
```

En el login, hago exactamente lo mismo, si la contraseña y usuario está correcto defino la sesión por 12 horas, en el único archivo donde destruyo la sesión es en **salir.php** y sólo es usado cuando se cierra sesión voluntariamente.

**¿Existe alguna solución u otra manera de definir lo que quiero hacer?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Existe alguna solución u otra manera de definir lo que quiero hacer?

Si. Este código lo uso para destruir la sesión tras cierto tiempo de inactividad:

```
// Definir máximo tiempo de poder estar inactivo (en horas)
define( 'MAX_SESSION_TIME', 3600 * 12 ); // 12 hora   

if ( isset( $_SESSION[ 'last_activity' ] ) && 
     ( time() - $_SESSION[ 'last_activity' ] ) > MAX_SESSION_TIME ) {

    session_unset();

    if ( ini_get( 'session.use_cookies' ) ) {

        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie( session_name(), '',
                   time() - MAX_SESSION_TIME,
                   $params[ 'path' ],
                   $params[ 'domain' ],
                   $params[ 'secure' ],
                   $params[ 'httponly' ] );
    }

    @session_destroy();     

    // Redireccionar
    header( 'Location: /dondeQuierasQueVaya' );
}

$_SESSION[ 'last_activity' ] = time();
```

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó, seguro el error estaba en mi código de inactividad.