# session php se cierra en servidor web

Tags: php

Inicio sesion de la siguiente forma:

```
session_start();
```

declaro la siguientes variablees de session

```
$_SESSION['user_token'] = $user_token;
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
$_SESSION['user_email'] = $login_email;
$_SESSION['user_role_id'] = $user_role_id;
```

pasan, mas o menos, 20 minutos de inactividad y la sesion se pierde

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION):

// resultado 
// array(0) { }
```

solo ocurre en el servidor web, cual puede ser la razon?

Comment: No seria `session_start();` ? te falta una t

Comment: Lo único bueno de PHP es [su documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.session.php). Incluso [tiempos de vida](https://www.php.net/manual/es/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) de sessiones y tal. ¡ Y en castellano !

Comment: Trauma, que bueno que aun asi... continues pendiente de las preguntas de php, lo de ´session.gc_maxlifetime´ la lo intente, no funciono.

Comment: Pues **indícalo** en la pregunta. Así los que quieran ayudarte podrán descartar cosas que **ya has probado**. Y, por favor, indica **exactamente** lo que has hecho.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres establecer sesiones más largas, añade un tiempo a la sesión, antes de iniciarla

```
$ttl = (60 * 60 * 24); # 1 día
session_set_cookie_params($ttl);
session_start();
```

En el momento que quieras terminar tu sesión, utiliza `session_destroy();` y `session_unset();` o también puedes establecer sesión vacia con `$_SESSION = [];`

También puedes consultar este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/97357/71085

Aquí se muestra cómo definir un tiempo a la sesión, y una vez pasado ese tiempo, redireccionar y destruir la sesión

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el problema esta en la configuaracion de `php` en el hosting

Por ahora implemente una funcion con jquery en el controlador que revise la `session` cada 20 minutos.

```
setInterval(sessionStarPHP, 1200000);

function sessionStarPHP() {
    $.post("sessionstart.php");
}
```

sessionstart.php

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
```